# Is there anyway to compare two fields in two models and store a field in the first model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
  class Register(models.Model):
           prollno=models.CharField(max_length=8)
           full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
           drollno=models.CharField(max_length=9)
           email=models.EmailField()
           gender=models.CharField(max_length=7,default="Male")    
           programme=models.CharField(max_length=100)
           course=models.CharField(max_length=100)
           yearofstudy=models.CharField(max_length=5)
           phone=models.BigIntegerField()
           city=models.TextField()
           pincode=models.IntegerField()
           address=models.TextField()
           isblacklisted=models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Blacklist(models.Model):    
  prollno=models.ForeignKey(Register)     
  full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100) 
  email=models.EmailField(max_length=55)
  phone=models.BigIntegerField()
```

I have two models Register and Blacklist and I have to compare the prollno of Register and Blacklist and if the values stored in both prollno are same, then I have to save the field isblacklisted of Register Model to True.

Comment: At which stage do you want to perform this action? While creating / updating a `Register` field or the `Blacklist` field or some other action?

Comment: While updating blacklist model with data, the field isblacklisted in Register model should change.

Answer (score 0):

The `prollno` field in the model class `Blacklist` is linked to the entire `Register` model instance.

Hence, I would suggest you to change the attribute name `prollno` in `Blacklist` to something like `register`. The `prollno` attribute's value can then be accesssed via `register.prollno`.

Now, when you have the entire `Register` instance linked to your `Blacklist` instance, you shouldn't need to use a `isblacklisted` attribute in class `Register` as that would create a circular pattern for no reason.

Hence, adding fields repetitive fields like `full_name`, `email`, and `phone` in class `Blacklist` should not be necessary if they are going to have the same values as that in the class `Register`.

## So, if you choose to:

### A. only mark the model `Register` as blacklisted and not add any additional info

Then, you can avoid creating the model `Blacklist` and just have the `isblacklisted` attribute in model `Register`.

A Blacklist Viewset can be created from the serializer of the model `Register` (say, `RegisterSerializer`) to fetch records that are blacklisted as follows:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class BlacklistViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Register.objects.filter(isblacklisted=True)
    serializer_class = serializers.RegisterSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = "__all__"
```

### B. have both the models `Register` and `Blacklist` in `models.py` with additional attributes in the classes.

You would want to remove the `isblacklisted` attribute from class `Register` to get rid of the circular pattern as described above.

Now, you can access the `Register` instances that are blacklisted by serializing the `Blacklist` model.

#### (1) If you still wish to change the `is_blacklisted` attribute

Then, your data should change while creating the `Blacklist` model instance.

Assuming the `prollno` is passed to the `BlacklistSerializer`, we can override the serializers code as:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class BlacklistSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            register_instance = models.Register.objects.get(
                prollno=validated_data['prollno']
            )
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
        else:
            instance, created = models.Blacklist.objects.get_or_create(
                register=register_instance
            )
            if created:
                register_instance.is_blacklisted = True
                register_instance.save()
```

#### (2) If you want to perform this action while updating the information of `Blacklist`

Then, we can just assume there is a `Blacklist` instance created without any `Register` instance linked. This does not seem to be a great implementation and would probably need an attribute like `blank=True` added to the attribute as:

```
class Blacklist(models.Model):    
  register=models.ForeignKey(Register, blank=True)
```

So, the update function would be as:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    try:
        register_instance = models.Register.objects.get(
            prollno=validated_data['prollno']
        )
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        instance.register=register_instance
        instance.save()
        register_instance.is_blacklisted = True
        register_instance.save()
```

Comment: Hey there is an issue in the solution you suggested. I upload the list of blacklisted people in the form of prollno,drollno,email,phone and with foreign key reference, I can't add only these values but all the above mentioned fields in register. Can you help me in this project, I myself a beginner in django, I have lot and lots of queries to ask.

Comment: Are you adding it via the BacklistSerializer? If so, are you sending the mentioned data to the serializer? I need more insight on your exact approach. 

Yes, I can assist you on your queries.